# RESTful API - Create "Service" and "Interface" for each Entity?

Tags: c#, rest, api, .net-core

I am studying RESTful API design and development in C# and .Net Core 3.0.

Two Points I need clarification on:

- Do I create a service and interface for every entity in my data layer?
  For example, I have my little "Wine Cellar" API for tracking personal wine ratings and other data.  For now, it uses MongoDB for data storage, but I will definitely have interfaces in order to switch to other storage options easily.  It will also make calls to at least one public API for some additional info, etc.  In my structure, I have Wine, WinePurchase, and Vendor entities.  This may grow to more entities as I develop the API and the corresponding MVC application that will be consuming my API.  Do I create three service classes and interfaces, one for each entity?  Or do I create a "Wine-Cellar" service and interface and cram all code in there?
- I am a little confused about when to call something a "Service" and when to call it a "Repository".
  I do understand the function of the Repository class -- a class to handle CRUD operations between the business layer and the database for a given entity.  Is a repository sometimes considered the same thing as a service, and vice versa?

The reason for my confusion, is that I have been completely through several Pluralsight courses on the subject.  I have seen some instructors refer to their data access classes as services, AND, and have seen them create a single service class for the Application overall.  Grant it, it was a simple application with not many entities, etc.  But I think that's adding confusion there if that's not a standard design practice.

Thank you.

Slider16

Comment: IMHO Everytime you see the word *repository*, and someone promoting them for entity framework, leave that site. that single word causes more problems then it has ever solved for EF

Comment: Can you expand on your opinion?  I don't understand your issue with repository pattern as it relates to Entity Framework.

Comment: As I understand, Repository is a class that abstracts the details of performing one/more business actions. A repository is not an executing thing. While a Service "WCP/Restful" is an executing thing that allows you to access/invoke functionality on a remote location.

Comment: _I will definitely have interfaces in order to switch to other storage options easily_ - something that actually happens very rarely. Interfaces are great for unit testing though.

Comment: Ex case for Repository: Say when you add a wine to your Cellar you buy it from a vendor. So getting a new wine requires adding records to multiple entities (3 in your case). In a Repository way of doing CRUD - you may have a method BuyNewWine - which in turn creates the necessary records for you in Wine, WinePurchase and Vendor tables.

Comment: Ahh - you meant Service in the Web Framework's POV. Service keyword comes from  (guess) Angular framework. Yes it is kind of synonymous to C# repository, but Repositories may have more functionality like storing data In-Memory and performing operations locally first and later write the final state to DB.

Comment: @stuartd _..something that actually happens very rarely._  Are you saying I should not create the interfaces to be implemented by my repositories?  Or are you saying that's a good thing that I'm doing?

Comment: Interfaces should have a purpose, and unit testing and DI is what I use them for the most. Unless you're sure that your current DB solution is only temporary, I wouldn't do anything that unnecessarily complicates your code.